# How do I remove folder and contents I have created while installing plugin

Tags: plugin-development

My plugin creates a folder in wordpress upload folder called my_plugin_folder.Now when I click uninstall the plugin the folder should be deleted. I tried the solutions given here but its not working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334398/how-to-delete-a-folder-with-contents-using-php

Answer (score 2):

In WP you have 2 solutions for code to be excecuted during your plugin uninstall process.

### First solution

In your plugin's root folder, create the file `uninstall.php`. This file will be loaded automatically by WP during uninstall process. Still, to prevent direct access, you need to make sure we're in the uninstall process for example by checking the `WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN` global.

```
// If uninstall.php is not called by WordPress, die
if ( ! defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) {
    die;
}

delete_folders();

// ...
```

### Second solution

In your main plugin file, use [`register_uninstall_hook`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/).

```
register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_uninstall' );

function plugin_uninstall() {
    delete_folders();

    // ...
}
```